# Iframe url trigger outer form

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Iframe third party payment inner form inside my outer form.
that mean right now I have tow buttons. one for the payment form, and another to submit the entire form.
how can I triger my outer form to send all details, while the inner payment form succes (the iframe redirect to another specific page).

BTW, I do not have acces to the inner third party payment form html

Comment: It should be simple.  I need the code that trigger the submit button when the iframe url changed....

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<iframe src="inner-form.html" onLoad="checkLocation(this.contentWindow.location);"></iframe>
```

And in javascript:

```
function checkLocation(url) {
   if (url !="inner-form.html") {
        // Code for when iframe location url has been changed
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you decide the redirect page's url after inner form submits successfully?

If you can, try make the redirect page's url the same domain as your outer form, and place script in the target page:

```
<script>
  parent.doSubmit(data); // Customize the method name as you want
</script>
```

The problem is, where you can get the `data` object, it depends on how the 3rd party payment system gives you the payment result, mostly it is in your url's query string, so you may get `data` like this:

```
var data = /payment_result=([^&]+)/.exec(document.location.search)[1];
```

Note the code above is only a simple example, all things depend on the 3rd party payment system.

In your outer form's page, you should place a `<input type="hidden">` element in your form, so your form may look like:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="paymentResult" name="paymentResult" />
  ...Other fields
</form>
```

Then in your outer form page, you should have the `doSubmit` method:

```
function doSubmit(data) {
  document.getElementById('paymentResult').value = data; // Here you should translate the data to a string in order to post it via HTTP
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

This is a rough implement, you have to modify these codes to match the **inner-outer form** and **inner form - 3rd party system**

Comment: Thanks, can you explain it clearly. I am new in JS.  the redirect page can be any page that I want - without payment result.  so I can put my code in new page in my domain that will trigger the submit button on the outer from... now I just need to know how to do it :)